# What's the role of the scale matrix for the Inverse-Wishart and Wishart distributions?

Tags: bayesian, prior, wishart-distribution

What's the role of the scale matrix for the Inverse-Wishart and Wishart distributions?

The purpose of finding this information is to enlighten me on how should one decide on a prior for a positive-definite matrix. What's the rationale for the choice of a scale matrix?

I've searched the forum, but I couldn't find a similar question on this subject.